# Qt Linking with Firmata

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, qmake

I am running on a Windows 7 with Qt SDK(C++), Firmata, and Arduino Softaware

I was wondering why the firmata.h is not working

```
#ifndef Firmata_Boards_h
#define Firmata_Boards_h

#include <inttypes.h>

#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
#include "Arduino.h"    // for digitalRead, digitalWrite, etc
#else
#include "WProgram.h"
#endif
```

the problem is when i try to compile using Qt it says

```
D:\SGU\Semester 8\Program\OpenCVMultithreaded\Boards.h:9: error: Arduino.h: No such file or directory
```

can we really use firmata on Qt? because in the internet I only found Arduino software using firmata, not on Qt itself.

I tried :

```
INCLUDEPATH += "D:\opencv\build\include" 
INCLUDEPATH += "D:\opencv\build\include\opencv" 
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino" 
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware" 
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\lib" I
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries" 
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino\Arduino.h"
```

But it doesnt work.

Comment: Hi ! This error do not mean that you can or cannot use firmata on Qt. It only says that it didn't find any Arduino.h. Check your command lines and check if you have Arduino.h in the correct folder you included.

Comment: it is from arduino library, it will be troublesome to copy the code from the C:/Arduino directory because it have many files.

Comment: You don't have to copy any file, the important thing is at least to have these files. When you compile, you have to specified to the compiler where to find all the files you need to build your app. In your case, you probably missed a -IC:/Arduino in your command line.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a linking issue but a compilation issue, and has nothing to do with the specific library you are using. You probably haven't specified where to find the header files nor the library files.

In your project file (`.pro`) add

```
INCLUDEPATH += PATH_TO_ARDUINNO_HEADERS
```

for example `PATH_TO_ARDUINNO_HEADERS`  can be `C:/Arduino/include`.

To specify libraries you need to use the [LIBS](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) variables, for example

```
LIBS += "-Lc:/Arduino/lib" -larduinnoshared
```

See the [qmake reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-reference.html) for a complete guide on including\linking to external items

**Edit:** 
The include path is what is going to be prefixed to find `"Arduino.h"`.
So if the file is at

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino\Arduino.h"
```

you need to use

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino"
```

All the other paths you posted are invalid for this file. You put ***only directories*** containing header files in the includepath.

Comment: i already add it, still cant work

`INCLUDEPATH += "D:\opencv\build\include"
INCLUDEPATH += "D:\opencv\build\include\opencv"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\lib"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino\Arduino.h"`

Comment: your include path directives are incorrect. see my edit