# Qt with Firmata Library

Tags: c++, qt, firmata

i want to link Firmata library to qt

how do i do it?
using includepath?
i already change the environment variable in my pc to include the arduino folder in C:
and i already include in my .pro file of Qt like these

```
# OpenCv Configuration opencv-2.4.6
INCLUDEPATH += "D:\opencv\build\include"
INCLUDEPATH += "D:\opencv\build\include\opencv"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\lib"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino\Arduino.h"
LIBS += "D:\opencv\install\lib\libopencv_calib3d246.dll.a"
LIBS += "D:\opencv\install\lib\libopencv_contrib246.dll.a"
LIBS += "D:\opencv\install\lib\libopencv_core246.dll.a"
LIBS += "D:\opencv\install\lib\libopencv_flann246.dll.a"
LIBS += "D:\opencv\install\lib\libopencv_highgui246.dll.a"
LIBS += "D:\opencv\install\lib\libopencv_imgproc246.dll.a"
LIBS += "D:\opencv\install\lib\libopencv_objdetect246.dll.a"
LIBS += "D:\opencv\install\lib\libopencv_features2d246.dll.a"
LIBS += "D:\opencv\install\lib\libopencv_legacy246.dll.a"
LIBS += "D:\opencv\install\lib\libopencv_ml246.dll.a"
#LIBS += "D:\opencv\install\lib\libopencv_ts246.dll.a"
LIBS += "D:\opencv\install\lib\libopencv_video246.dll.a"
```

do i make some mistake? because Arduino.h in my Boards.h say there is no such file directory

below is the boards.h file:

```
#ifndef Firmata_Boards_h
#define Firmata_Boards_h

#include <inttypes.h>

#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
#include <Arduino.h>    // for digitalRead, digitalWrite, etc
#else
#include "WProgram.h"
#endif

// Normally Servo.h must be included before Firmata.h (which then includes
// this file).  If Servo.h wasn't included, this allows the code to still
// compile, but without support for any Servos.  Hopefully that's what the
// user intended by not including Servo.h
#ifndef MAX_SERVOS
#define MAX_SERVOS 0
#endif
```

Comment: actually, the problem could be with spaces in `INCLUDEPATH`

Comment: You should not ask two questions for one problem. Stay on your first topic please... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604214/qt-linking-with-firmata